# Use Regex to count the successor of zero for a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a project where I need to convert a string with some rules.

the string is: `"9: (play alice bob (s (s z)) (s (s (s z))))"`

The way i want to convert it is simply to remove the (s (s z)) part and instead count them like a successor of zero. For example

z = 0

(s z) = 1

(s (s z)) = 2

So the string `"9: (play alice bob (s (s z)) (s (s (s z))))"  --> "9: (play alice bob 2 3"`

#### Tried

I have already tried some things with regex but couldn't find anything that would give me the right answer. Things I tried so far is.

`re.findall(r"\((.+)\)",line)[0]  --> play alice bob (s (s z)) (s (s (s z)))`

and if I do it again on the string inside

`re.findall(r"\((.+)\)",line)[0]  --> s (s z)) (s (s (s z))`

Don´t really have any idea how to proceed from this part or if there is something more simple.

Comment: Is there a max on `(s (s (s ....etc`?

Comment: Replace `"z"` with `"0"` once, then repeatedly replace `r"\(s (\d+)\)"` with `lambda m: str(int(m.group(1)) + 1)` until no changes take place.  (`re.sub()` doesn't return any indication of how many replacements were made, so you'd need to compare the before/after lengths of the string to detect the end of the process.)

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of occurrences of `s` in `\([sz].*?\)`.

```
s = "9: (play alice bob (z) (s (s z)) (s (s (s z))))"
re.sub(r"\([sz].*?\)", lambda m: str(m.group().count("s")), s).replace(")", "") + ")"
```

result:

```
9: (play alice bob 0 2 3)
```